# Game Website requires glitch fix

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making a snake game, and when i try this game.... i noticed a huge error but i don't know how to fix it. Basically, when you play it, if the snake collides with the right hand side of the canvas, the game goes on but if it hits on the top, bottom or left side of the canvas, the game ends, as expected. So how do i fix this:

So how would i ensure that when the snake collides with the right hand side of the canvas, the game ends rather than carries on?? Where is the fix to a certain part of this code?

Comment: Create a working fiddle somewhere, so we can test, please

Comment: You go to jsfiddle.net, or you use the snippet-function on this very page?

Comment: Yes, you have, but I can't play it to test it. You need to make sure that the test / example actually works (apart from the fact that it of course won't notice the right wall). Currently I can't move the snake (arrow-keys doesn't work, it seems) Hence I can't actually test it (unless you redesign it to go from left to right, instead of from up to down by default)

Comment: Would be smart to mention that it only works in Chrome... (Firefox returns with a window.event undefined-error, doesn't allow for using arrowkeys to control).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure why, but it works: change the `if (snakeX == -1 || snakeX == w / snakeSize || snakeY == -1 || snakeY == h / snakeSize || checkCollision(snakeX, snakeY, snake)) {` to `if (snakeX == -1 || snakeX == 56  || snakeY == -1 || snakeY == h / snakeSize || checkCollision(snakeX, snakeY, snake)) {` it works, but I'm not entirely sure why it works. The point is that the right-side isn't met before the snake has traveled a long way past the right border (the width of the element is set to `565`, and if you log the `snakeX`-variable, you will see that the original code stops when it hits `565` as value). Changing the comparison works, but I'm not a 100% sure why it works (sorry about that). I'm a bit too tired right now.

Comment: First - you shouldn't remove the code... that means this thread is no completely useless to anyone trying to do the same you just did. And that would basically just be displaying / inserting a text-node (an element with the text in it) instead of just removing the container for the snake-game, or you could just do an alert() : `alert('Game over');` when it ends.

Comment: Ah, and of course you would have to add the score to that alert, somehow - I don't have the code right now, but I'm assuming you have a function or variable with the score? Then just reuse that.

Comment: Oh i see, just did it and it worked. Thanks again :)